# How to search word and replace in 2D array

Tags: c#, arrays, algorithm, multidimensional-array

i am new to c#. How to search for the whole word and replace it with the word that i want. For example find 'SUCCESS' and replace with 'XXXXXXX'. I can replace it with 1 word as you u can see from the if loop but i want replace whole loop.

Can anyone give me hint?

```
public class CrossWordTable
    {
        public char[,] CrossWord
        {
            get
            {
                var table = new char[,]
                {
                    {'S','U','C','C','E','S','S' },
                    {'E','U','S','S','E','C','U'},
                    {'U','S','C','C','C','E','C'},
                    {'S','S','U','C','E','C','C'},
                    {'S','E','S','S','E','S','S'},
                    {'U','C','S','E','U','S','S'},
                    {'C','C','S','S','E','E','S'},
                    {'S','U','S','S','S','S','E'},
                    {'U','S','E','S','S','C','S'}

                };
                return table;
            }
        }

        public void PrintCrossWord()
        {
            PrintCrossWord(CrossWord);
        }

        static int[] x = { 0, 0, -1, 1, 1, -1, -1, 1 };
        static int[] y = { -1, 1, 0, 0, 1, -1, 1, -1 };

        public void PrintCrossWord(char[,] crossWordTable)
        {
            var totalRowNumber = crossWordTable.GetLength(0);
            var totalColumnNumber = crossWordTable.GetLength(1);
            String word;
            word = "SUCCESS";
            int len = word.Length;

            Console.WriteLine("*** Crossword Table *****");
            for (var row = 0; row < totalRowNumber; row++)
            {
                for (var column = 0; column < totalColumnNumber; column++)
                {
                    if (CrossWord[row, column] != word[0])
                    {



                        
                        Console.Write(crossWordTable[row, column]);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        

                        crossWordTable[row, column] = 'X';
                        Console.Write(crossWordTable[row, column]);
                    }
                }
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
            Console.WriteLine("************************");

        }
```

Comment: Do you want to replace the word success reading in any direction? Horizontally, vertically, diagonally, and backwards for all of the previous?

Comment: @insane_developer Yes. I want replace it in all direction.

Comment: @JayJ if its not a big array you can just go trough for loop in all directions.

Comment: @VukUskokovic something like this? len is length of word

for (int dir = 0; dir < 8; dir++) { 

            for (k = 1; k < len; k++) { 

                if (rd >= R || rd < 0 || cd >= C || cd < 0) { 
                    break; 
                } 
  
                if (grid[rd, cd] != word[k]) { 
                    break; 
                } 
  
                rd += x[dir]; 
                cd += y[dir];
  crossWordTable[row, column] = 'X';
                Console.Write(crossWordTable[row, column]);
            } 
  
        }

Comment: @JayJ try running the code and see from the output, rather than posting code in the comment.

Comment: You can't replace as you go because that will result in not being able to identify other options of the word that intersect a character. I think you have to do backtracking here to first save all the row,col positions that will get an 'X' after you exhaust all possible reads from each location. Then you can replace characters.

Comment: @insane_developer i did tried replace as it go. if there is 'S' it will replace 'X' eight times since there are 8 ways. Can you explain more on how can i do backtracking?

Comment: You can check out many applications of the [backtracking algorithm](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/backtracking-algorithms/). It involves recursion, and it's not a simple thing to do. Writing recursive code is always tricky.

Comment: @JayJ you simple you just replace all chars from end to start to X it isnt tied to that word, once you find the word at x, y just go back the length and replace it all.

Comment: @JayJ you can use for loop with two integers no need for two loops

Comment: Copy the whole structure and use it for the replacements.  Read from the original so that modifications don't affect future searches.  Iterate all rows,columns and diagonals.  Not too bad I don't think - good easily be an interview level question.

Comment: @VukUskokovic you mean i just need to replace all chars from end to start to X which isnt tied to the word? I dont get on how to get back to the length and replace it. Can u show me how the loop look like with 2 integers?

Comment: @MichaelDorgan i get the idea, but i just don't know how to perform because i have little know in c#

Comment: @JayJ I modified your class to work with any array, and it finds matches in all directions.

Comment: @VukUskokovic I did it as you said and it worked! Thank you everyone.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way of doing it. It's a recursive solution. My first attempt to refactor the code failed, and I chose not to invest more time trying.

```
public class CrossWordTable
    {
        private readonly char[,] _crossword;
        private readonly string _word;
        private const char MARKER = 'X';
        private readonly int _rowLength;
        private readonly int _colLength;
        private HashSet<(int, int)> _points;

        public CrossWordTable(char[,] crossword, string word)
        {
            _crossword = crossword;
            _word = word.ToUpper();
            _rowLength = _crossword.GetLength(0);
            _colLength = _crossword.GetLength(1);
            _points = new HashSet<(int, int)>();
        }

        private enum Direction { Right, Down, Left, Up, DiagonalUpRight, DiagonalUpLeft, DiagonalDownRight, DiagonalDownLeft }

        public void PrintCrossWord()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < _rowLength; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < _colLength; j++)
                {
                    Console.Write($"{_crossword[i, j]}  ");
                }
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
        }

        public void SolveCrossWord()
        {
            for (int r = 0; r < _rowLength; r++)
            {
                for (int c = 0; c < _colLength; c++)
                {
                    Explore(r, c, 0, Direction.Right);
                    Explore(r, c, 0, Direction.Down);
                    Explore(r, c, 0, Direction.Left);
                    Explore(r, c, 0, Direction.Up);
                    Explore(r, c, 0, Direction.DiagonalUpRight);
                    Explore(r, c, 0, Direction.DiagonalUpLeft);
                    Explore(r, c, 0, Direction.DiagonalDownRight);
                    Explore(r, c, 0, Direction.DiagonalDownLeft);
                }
            }
            foreach (var (row, col) in _points)
            {
                _crossword[row, col] = MARKER;
            }
            PrintCrossWord();
        }

        private bool Explore(int row, int col, int wordIndex, Direction direction)
        {
            if (wordIndex == _word.Length)
                return true;
            if (_crossword[row, col] == _word[wordIndex])
            {
                if (direction == Direction.Right && col + _word.Length - wordIndex <= _colLength)
                {
                    var added = _points.Add((row, col));
                    if (!Explore(row, col + 1, wordIndex + 1, direction))
                    {
                        if (added)
                            _points.Remove((row, col));
                        return false;
                    }
                    return true;
                }
                else if (direction == Direction.Down && row + _word.Length - wordIndex <= _rowLength)
                {
                    var added = _points.Add((row, col));
                    if (!Explore(row + 1, col, wordIndex + 1, direction))
                    {
                        if (added)
                            _points.Remove((row, col));
                        return false;
                    }
                    return true;
                }
                else if (direction == Direction.Left && col - (_word.Length - wordIndex) >= -1)
                {
                    var added = _points.Add((row, col));
                    if (!Explore(row, col - 1, wordIndex + 1, direction))
                    {
                        if (added)
                            _points.Remove((row, col));
                        return false;
                    }
                    return true;
                }
                else if (direction == Direction.Up && row - (_word.Length - wordIndex) >= -1)
                {
                    var added = _points.Add((row, col));
                    if (!Explore(row - 1, col, wordIndex + 1, direction))
                    {
                        if (added)
                            _points.Remove((row, col));
                        return false;
                    }
                    return true;
                }
                else if (direction == Direction.DiagonalUpRight && row - (_word.Length - wordIndex) >= -1 && col + _word.Length - wordIndex <= _colLength)
                {
                    var added = _points.Add((row, col));
                    if (!Explore(row - 1, col + 1, wordIndex + 1, direction))
                    {
                        if (added)
                            _points.Remove((row, col));
                        return false;
                    }
                    return true;
                }
                else if (direction == Direction.DiagonalUpLeft && row - (_word.Length - wordIndex) >= -1 && col - (_word.Length - wordIndex) >= -1)
                {
                    var added = _points.Add((row, col));
                    if (!Explore(row - 1, col - 1, wordIndex + 1, direction))
                    {
                        if (added)
                            _points.Remove((row, col));
                        return false;
                    }
                    return true;
                }
                else if (direction == Direction.DiagonalDownRight && row + _word.Length - wordIndex <= _rowLength && col + _word.Length - wordIndex <= _colLength)
                {
                    var added = _points.Add((row, col));
                    if (!Explore(row + 1, col + 1, wordIndex + 1, direction))
                    {
                        if (added)
                            _points.Remove((row, col));
                        return false;
                    }
                    return true;
                }
                else if (direction == Direction.DiagonalDownLeft && row + _word.Length - wordIndex <= _rowLength && col - (_word.Length - wordIndex) >= -1)
                {
                    var added = _points.Add((row, col));
                    if (!Explore(row + 1, col - 1, wordIndex + 1, direction))
                    {
                        if (added)
                            _points.Remove((row, col));
                        return false;
                    }
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
```

The class takes a two dimensional array, and calling `SolveCrossWord()` solves the crossword and prints the result.